# Change column order in table of postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to change the column order in the table of postgressql. But I didn't get any clue or answer. 
I think this functionality is add in new version. 
I am using postgres 11.
Ex

```
No column 
1     Id
2    Lastname
3    Firstname
```

Now i want to change Firstname on 2nd position.

Comment: add more details

Comment: https://tableplus.com/blog/2018/09/postgresql-is-it-possible-to-alter-column-order-position-in-a-table.html

Comment: @Raghavendra added

Comment: I have added my answer..thanks

Comment: Why do you think you need that. The order of columns in a table is completely meaningless

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name actually I have numbers of field and some type of column I want at last. Thats why I want this.

Comment: As I said: the order of column in a relational table is completely meaningless. Save yourself the trouble. Just put them in the SELECT list in the order you want. Or create a view if you have bad code that uses `select *`

Answer (score 3):

You would have to drop and re-create the table or at least the `lastname` column for that:

```
BEGIN;
ALTER TABLE atable RENAME lastname TO oldcol;
ALTER TABLE atable ADD lastname text NOT NULL;
UPDATE atable SET lastname = oldcol;
ALTER TABLE atable DROP oldcol;
COMMIT;
```

But the exercise is pretty pointless, since you can always determine the order in which you get the columns in the `SELECT` clause. You aren't using `SELECT *`, are you? That would be problematic for other reasons as well; it is only useful for ad-hoc queries.